# Height of square pyramid stacking of spheres with different radii

Tags: 3d, spheres, packing-problem

What is the total height of a system consisting of 4 spheres of radius $x$ on top of which is a sphere of radius $y$? (Such that the top sphere is in the 'crevice' of the others, as seen when packing spheres.)

I know a solution that works for spheres of the same radius, but not one where the radii are different.

Is there a generalised equation that works for varying numbers of spheres? For example, where the 9 bottom spheres have radius $x$, the 4 middle spheres have radius $y$, and the top sphere has radius $z$.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Mathematics StackExchange! Have you tried using the SAME method for this problem? If so, what did you find ? Please update the post with this information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the bottom four spheres have radius $R_1$ , and the the top sphere have radius $R_2$, then using the distance formula between the center of one the four spheres and the center of the top sphere we can find the position of this top sphere.

Let the center of one of the bottom spheres be $( R_1, R_1, R_1 )$ and the top sphere $ (0, 0, z_2 )$ , then expressing the distance between the two centers as the sum of the two radii, we end up with

$ R_1^2 + R_1^2 + (z_2 - R_1)^2 = (R_1 + R_2)^2 $

Hence,

$ z_2 = R_1 + \sqrt{ (R_1 + R_2)^2 - 2 R_1^2 } $

For the three-layer set up with $9$ balls at the bottom layer, then $4$ in the second layer, then $1$ at the top, you will have similar to the above

$ z_2 = R_1 + \sqrt{ (R_1 + R_2)^2 - 2 R_1^2 } $

and

$ z_3 = z_2 + \sqrt{ (R_2 + R_3)^2 - 2 R_2^2 } $

Comment: Does this work for spheres of differing radii, as the distance between the two centre points is not equal to the sum of the two radii?

Comment: The distance between the two centers is always equal to the sum of the two radii

Comment: Just to double-check. If you take $z_2$ and add the two radii, that is the total height of the whole system?

For example, if $R_1 = 1$ and $R_2 = 1.5$, then the total height of the system is $\frac{7+\sqrt{17}}{2} + 2.5 \approx 4.561552813$?

Comment: Yes.  That's correct.

Comment: I have encountered a problem, if you say that system $A$ has the bottom spheres as radius 1 and top sphere as radius 1.5, and that system $B$ has the bottom spheres as radius 1.5 and top sphere as radius 1, logic would dictate that system $A$ has a greater total height, yet:

$h(A) = \frac{7+\sqrt{17}}{2} + 2.5 \approx 4.561552813$ and $h(B) = \frac{8+\sqrt{7}}{2} + 2.5 \approx 5.322875656$

What happened? /gen

Comment: What logic did you use in your conclusion that system A has a greater total height than system B?

Comment: Since the bottom spheres in system $A$ are smaller, there is a shallower 'hole' for the larger sphere to sit in. In system $B$, the bottom spheres are larger, meaning the smaller sphere can 'sink' into the gap further. Does that make sense sorry- I'm not very good at explaining things. :)

Comment: Yes, your logic makes sense.  As shown in this [geogebra worksheet](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/acp4suds).  So you must have miscalculated the total height of system $B$.  Because indeed $h(B) \lt h(A)$

Comment: hmm- I'm not sure where I went wrong. What was the equation you have for $h(B)$?

Comment: $h(B) = R_2 + R_1 + \sqrt{ (R_1 + R_2)^2 - 2 R_1^2 } = 2.5 + \sqrt{ (2.5)^2 - 2 (1.5)^2 } = 2.5 + \sqrt{1.75} \approx 3.822875 $

Comment: Sorry- I just looked at your formula, you say $R_2 + R_1 + ...$ but in your answer, you only say $R_1 + ...$. Which is correct? :)

Comment: The formula in the answer is for the height of the center of the top sphere.  The total height is that value plus the radius of the top sphere which is $R_2$

Comment: Ah, that clears things up! Thank you again! :D